# Bootstrap 3.0 - Displaying multiple Facebook albums in tabbable panes

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Good evening everyone,

I have a 3 tab window where I want each tab to display a different Facebook album when the user clicks the corresponding tab. The first(and default) tab works perfectly. However when I click the second tab and it just shows a black screen. It also seems whatever FB album ID I put in tab2 overrides the content of tab1. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <div id="galleria">
    <script>
       Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
       Galleria.run('#galleria', {
            facebook: 'album:303814463041408',
            width: 458,
            height: 250,
            wait:true,
            lightbox: true});
     </script>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
     <div id="galleria">
     <script>
        Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        Galleria.run('#galleria', {
           facebook: 'album:323687541054100',
           width: 458,
           height: 250,
           wait:true,
           lightbox: true});
       </script>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      <p>tab3 tab3 tab3</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because both tabs' content are using the same ID `galleria`. Try changing them to `id="galleria1"` and `id="galleria2"`, then update each script to target the appropriate divs: `#galleria1` and `#galleria2`.